# Encoding issue when reading from Google translator API and writing to properties file

Tags: java, utf-8, resourcebundle

I am using Google translator API to generate Arabic property file from English property file.

1. Making a `URL` connection and making a GET request to the `URL`.,passing original language, translation language and value to be translated

```java
URLConnection urlCon = null;  
String urlStr = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";
URL url = new URL(urlStr + "?key=" + apikey + "&source=" + origlang + "&target=" + translateToLang + "&q=" + value);  
urlCon = url.openConnection();
urlCon.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);  
urlCon.setReadTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);  
urlCon.setDoInput(true);  
urlCon.setDoOutput(true);  
urlCon.setUseCaches(false);  
((HttpURLConnection) urlCon).setRequestMethod("GET");  
urlCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
```

2. Reading the response from the URL connection through inputstream reader. Passing UTF-8 in the encoding parameter.

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((URLConnection) urlCon).getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
/* Reading the response line by line */  
StringBuffer responseString = new StringBuffer();   
String nextLine = null;  
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
    responseString.append(nextLine);  
}  
// if response is null or empty, throw exception  
String response = responseString.toString();
```

3. Parsing the JSON received through GSON parser

```java
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(response);  
JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();  
jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");  
JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");  
jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();  
String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString();
```

4. Writing the translated value in a new property file through `fileoutstream`

```
FileOutputStream foutStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
foutStream.write(key.getBytes());
foutStream.write("=".getBytes());
foutStream.write(transByte.getBytes());foutStream.write("\n".getBytes());
```

The issue is I am getting garbled text(?????) written in the new property file for Arabic language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `transByte.getBytes()`, the Arabic translation is encoded with your platform default encoding, which will only handle Arabic if your machine is configured for UTF-8 or Arabic. Otherwise, characters will be replaced by `'�'` or `'?'` .

Create a new `Properties` instance, and populate it using [`setProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) calls. Then when you [store it,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) the proper escaping will be applied to your Arabic text, which is necessary because property files are encoded with ISO-8859-1 (an encoding for Western Latin characters).

Alternatively, you can [store the `Properties` using a `Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-) instance that is configured with whatever encoding you choose, but the encoding isn't stored in the file itself, so you will need meta-data or a convention to set the correct encoding when reading the file again.

Finally, you can [store the `Properties` in an XML format,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) which will use UTF-8 by default, or you can specify another encoding. The file itself will specify the encoding, so it's easier to use an optimal encoding for each language.

Trying to emit a file format using custom string concatenation, as you are doing, is an oft-repeated recipe for disaster. Whether it's XML, JSON, or a simple properties file, it's far too easy to overlook special cases that require escape sequences, etc. Use a library designed to emit the format instead.

Comment: Thanks. Using a Writer helped. Also, what libraries can be used (as you suggested in the last point)?

Comment: @user1502901 In this case, using `Properties` rather than writing strings variables and literals.